# how to run multi clients at the same time in websockets?

Tags: python, websocket

so, i created a simple code to make clients and one server with websockets

so this is for client code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import os
import glob
import time
import base64


def load_image_data():  

    os.chdir('./50_mb')
    for image in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
        with open(image, 'rb') as imageFile:
            str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

async def send_message():

    uri = "ws://localhost:8765"

    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:

        start = time.time()
        await websocket.send(str(load_image_data()))
        end = time.time()

        print('time spent : {} ms'.format((end - start)*1000))

def main():

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(send_message())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

and this is for server:

```
import asyncio 
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"< {name}")

    greeting = f"Hello {name} !"

    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print(f">{greeting}")

def main():
    start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765)

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

can i run multiple clients at the same time to the server ? i've been searching the answer here but none of them solved my problem. thanks in advance !

**note:** all clients has the same code

Comment: Have you tried running multiple clients with your current code? Did it work? To my mind, it should just work as is.

Comment: that client.py just for one client, but i have another the same client code. but i don't know how to run them simultaneously @9000

Comment: Open several terminal windows, or IDLE instances, or what have you, and run multiple copies!

Comment: yes, you can run multiple clients at same time